# How to query UK aggregate data from the UK land registry database

Tags: sparql

So I'm trying to recreate the third graph on the [UK Land Registry database](https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ukhpi/browse?from=2020-10-01&location=http%3A%2F%2Flandregistry.data.gov.uk%2Fid%2Fregion%2Funited-kingdom&to=2021-10-01&lang=en) but every example query splits by region, I'm not experienced in creating queries like this so have no idea how to modify the below to return data for the whole of UK rather than by region.

If anyone is able to give me some clues it would be much appreciated!

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# House price index for all regions within a given date range
SELECT ?region ?date ?hpi
{
  ?region ukhpi:refPeriodStart ?date ;
          ukhpi:housePriceIndex ?hpi
  FILTER (
    ?date > "2008-12-31"^^xsd:date &&
    ?date < "2009-03-01"^^xsd:date
  )
}
```

Comment: just omit the region if you don't need it. You can compute any aggregate function without grouping by the region. Nevertheless, I doubt you will be able to compute the percentage difference w.r.t. to the previous month as shown in the 3rd graph - that is impossible with a single SPARQL query given that this would need some window functions.

Comment: I can't see in the query above how to omit the region, just removing region above creates an error. And I don't understand which prefix would need to change to aggregate over the country (And I don't want to simply average over all regions after querying as I assume that would overweight some regions wrt others). Once i can get the raw data I can use python to calculate running percentages. I just want to work out how to get dates / HPI for whole of UK.

Comment: not sure if I understand your concerns, but as long as you're not grouping by `?region` variable, any aggregate function will be on the whole country. Just don't use the variable. You can for example do: `SELECT (avg(?hpi) as ?avg_hpi)
{
  ?region ukhpi:refPeriodStart ?date ;
          ukhpi:housePriceIndex ?hpi
  FILTER (
    ?date > "2008-12-31"^^xsd:date &&
    ?date < "2009-03-01"^^xsd:date
  )
}` - this will compute the average HPI for the given date on the whole UK country data